# Remove horizontal divider line from mfc wizard

Tags: c++, mfc, dialog

I have a mfc wizard in which I implemented code for re-sizability. There's a horizontal divider line at the bottom of the wizard dialog, as shown by the red arrow in the picture, which I need to get rid of.

[image: wizard dialog with unwanted line]

Since I don't know the ID of that line, I haven't included it in my resize code. Because of that, when I resize the wizard, the line keeps messing up the dialog.

[image: Resized wizard]

It would be a great help if the ID of the divider or a method to remove it can be found.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my machine (Win8.1) the ID is 3026, as shown with Spy++; have a look if it's the same on yours and/or other machines. Otherwise you could still enumerate all windows and look for the one with the STATIC window class. Then just DestroyWindow() that.

That said, I don't think the line is the issue here; the issue is that your dialog isn't redrawing itself properly. And I speculate that this is caused by it assuming a fixed size. Wizards aren't meant to be resized (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774544%28v=vs.85%29.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb246463%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Even if you destroy the line, other content you will put there is going to be invalidated incorrectly as well, I think.

Maybe you can work around it by manually invalidating or playing with various clip related windows styles. However the real answer is 'don't do that'.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I checked with spy (which I learnt to use today), it's 3026 in my computer too. :D